# How to send Maui XAML Bound value to parameter in code-behind C# Converter?

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, converters, maui

I need to bind to several custom converters in Maui XAML that simply format strings in very complex ways.

I created a test converter in C# code-behind and can see that it gets called but I cannot get the parameter to contain the Value inside BegTime, only a string or a Path?

My converter gets called, but the parameter is Never the actual bound Value.

I can send the converter a fixed string of "BegTime" (Not the value of BegTime)

```
<Label Text="{Binding BegTime, 
    Converter={StaticResource FormatJobTimeBegTime},
    ConverterParameter=BegTime}" />
```

I can send it a ((Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Binding)parameter).Path containing 'BegTime' (but Not the value of BegTime).

```
<Label Text="{Binding BegTime, 
    Converter={StaticResource FormatJobTimeBegTime},
    ConverterParameter={Binding BegTime}}" />
```

But I cannot seem to send the parameter the actual data (a string containing a time) that is Inside BegTime??

here's the XAML declaration of the Code-behind Converter:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converters:FormatJobTimeBegTimeConverter x:Key="FormatJobTimeBegTime" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

and FormatJobTimeBegTimeConverter IS getting called as I can set a breakpoint and observe the parameter

```
public class FormatJobTimeBegTimeConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        // I can set a breakpoint here to inspect the value of the parameter
        //parameter must contain a string with the value Inside BegTime???

        return "mm/dd/yy";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

BegTime is a Property in a class:

```
public sealed partial class TicketItem: ObservableObject {
    [ObservableProperty]
    public DateTime begTime; 
    [ObservableProperty]
    public DateTime endTime; 
 }
```

```
 public sealed partial class WhereSchedClient : ObservableObject {
    [ObservableProperty]
    public string company; 

    [ObservableProperty]
    public List<TicketItem> ticketItems;
 }
```

```
public class InvoiceViewModel  {
    public List<WhereSchedClient> WhereSchedClients { get; set; }
}
```

I have no trouble at all displaying the time in the XAML like:

```
<Label Text="{Binding BegTime}" />
```

Here's the XAML which works perfectly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage x:Name="parentView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MauiSched"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MauiSched"
             x:Class="MauiSched.Schedule"
             Title="Schedule">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converters:FormatJobTimeBegTimeConverter x:Key="FormatJobTimeBegTime" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
            <!-- Header section -->
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding WhereSchedClients}" BackgroundColor="Blue">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Company}" />
                            <!-- Invoice items section -->
                            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Green">
                                <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding TicketItems}">
                                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="20">
                                                <Label Text="{Binding BegTime, 
                                                    Converter={StaticResource FormatJobTimeBegTime},
                                                    ConverterParameter={Binding BegTime}}" />
                                                <Label Text="{Binding BegTime}" />          
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

What I'm having trouble doing is passing the Value inside of BegTime (which is a date string) as a parameter to the FormatJobTimeBegTimeConverter so that it can be formatted properly.

Comment: You shouldn’t need to pass a parameter containing the bound value, it should automatically be passed in as the first parameter

Comment: If Jason’s comment isn’t enough info (parameter “value” should have what you need), then add to question the declaration of BegTime. Also, give more details of the situation: Is BegTime a property in a viewmodel? Are you able to Bind to other properties? What displays if you remove the converter, just do `={Binding BegTime}`? There are many older questions about binding at StackOverflow, related to Xamarin.Forms. Consider searching for those.

Comment: hI @Jason and @ToolmakerSteve!  I added more classes & the viewModel & the full XAML.   If I change my attempt at using the converter to: <Label Text="{Binding BegTime,  Converter={StaticResource FormatJobTimeBegTime}}" />,  when it hits the breakpoint it get a null.

So the Only thing I've been able to get in he parameter value is a null or simply the text that I place in the ConverterParameter?   I'm obviously making some really stupid mistake and completely missing something .. Obvious??   But I don't have trouble .. Binding .. just with passing the value that is bound to the converter??

Comment: Are you sure the converter is not called once before the value is set and then again after the value is set?

Comment: @Jason I watched every single breakpoint for all the items - and the parameter was always null?

I've been passing parameters to code-behind since ASP.NET using .NET framework (but I'm new to Maui and newer concepts).  This is so basic .. I must be missing something very simple?

Could you please confirm exactly the syntax for <Label Text="{Binding BegTime,  Converter={StaticResource FormatJobTimeBegTime}}" /> as if you were speaking to a child - as that's what I feel like - being unable to get one short line of code working?

Comment: See the answer below

Comment: I'd previously been trying to use a ValueConverter for binding to a property in the parent of a nested StackLayout (never got the binding to work using a converter) and was never getting anything in the value -  so I was only looking for data in the parameter for this conversion (instead of the value).

Major blunder!!

Thanks for everyone's patience .. totally my mistake for not caching my own error.  And .. THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `<Label Text="{Binding BegTime, Converter={StaticResource FormatJobTimeBegTime}}"`, **BegTime** can be passed into Converters without ConverterParameter.

> The Convert method is called when data moves from the source to the target in OneWay or TwoWay bindings. The value parameter is the object or value from the data-binding source.

More info, you could refer to [Binding value converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/converters?view=net-maui-7.0#binding-value-converters-1)

Look at the following code, BegTime will be passed to the first **value** object not **parameter** object as Jason mentioned.

```
public class FormatJobTimeBegTimeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public FormatJobTimeBegTimeConverter()
    {
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DateTime dt = (DateTime)value;
        return string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}",dt.Month,dt.Day,dt.Year);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This worked well on my side.

By the way, ConverterParameter is not BindableObject so you cannnot use a binding for it.

Hope it works.

Comment: My bad.  As i explained in another comment .. I'd only seen data returned in the parameter so I wasn't even looking at the value.  

Thank you for taking the time and please excuse my incompetence.   Getting a bit 'snow blind' from looking at code all day lol!!

Comment: So glad you solved it! Happy coding!